# Shapes of hidden 3d convolutional network layers, how to compute it?

Tags: machine-learning, multidimensional-array, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I want to computer the shape of a given hidden layer output of a CNN, so suppose the input shape is (27,27,27,1) ie one image channe, the first convolutional layer is a 16X(3,3,3) kernels, stride is 1 and padding is 0, so the output shape of this layer is : (25,25,25,16), the 16 corresponds to the number of kernels in this layer, so here we have 16 volumes of shape (25,25,25)
after that, we have a second convolutional layer of 32X(3,3,3) kernels, stride is 1 and the padding is 0, so every kernels in this layers should (normally) be applied to the whole input volume of this layers i.e to the (25,25,25,16), but here the output is of shape (23,23,23,32), 
what i understand if I base myself on conv2d, is that every kernel is applied on the whole volume in the input, and we stack the result of all kernels to have a deep volume in the output of the layer in question. 
so I did not understand how we got this (23,23,23,32), and where is gone the fourth dimension of the output of the first layer (ie 16)??

Answer (score 0):

Considering only the second layer (ignoring bias)

- Input shape: (25, 25, 25, 16)
- Kernel size: (3, 3, 3)
- Output channels: 32
- Total number of weights: 16 * 32 * 3 * 3 * 3

Similar to the way that 2D conv layers are really performing multiple 3D convolutions, 3D conv layers are really performing multiple 4D convolution. Specifically, the 3D conv layer in question is performing 32 convolutions, each with a kernel of size (3, 3, 3, 16). The result of one of these convolution operations on the input feature is (23, 23, 23, 1). After all 32 of these operations are completed they are stacked along the channel dimension resulting in a final output shape of (23, 23, 23, 32).